# Add an empty value in dropdown list when using DataSource C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm trying to create a filter through `DropDownList`. 
They are using Datasources. 
The problem is - these sources don't include empty value and filter always works. Of course I don't need it. I tryied to add ListItem right incide of `DropDownList` but it didn't help.

Here is one of my `DropDownList`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds"
     DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id">
</asp:DropDownList>                                
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conStr %>" 
     OnInit="sds_Init"></asp:SqlDataSource>>
```

Will be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in code behind:

```
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
```

Or:

```
ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "-1"));
```

Or on your .aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds"
     DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id">
     <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value ="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Or potentially in your SQL:

```
SELECT "--Select--" AS [name], -1 as [id]
UNION
SELECT ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tryied all except of last method, and unfortunatly none of this helped. 
I can't try the last one due to some other reasons.
Visual Studio says that there is no definition for "Add" at all. 
As for the rest  two - I understand that it surely should help, I also tryied the one in .aspx as I wrote but nothing happend. 
If you have any other ideas - I would be glad!

Comment: @vitaly try to use *ddl.Items.Add()* method, it is correct version of that

Comment: @NikolaiDante thank you, it works. But can you advice, where should I put it? And why putting it into 'Page_Load' method and 'OnInit' don't work? I tryed with button but it doesn't fit me.

Comment: It would be down to the [Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). I've done it `on load` before, but that was along side where the ddl was being populated.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing the same thing this way, Try this once

```
 AffiliatesDomain affiliateDomain = new AffiliatesDomain();
 List<usp_selectAffiliatesForMasterResult> objListAffiliate = new List<usp_selectAffiliatesForMasterResult>();
 objListAffiliate = affiliateDomain.SelctAffiliatesForMasterAgent();
 ddlAffiliate.DataSource = objListAffiliate;
 ddlAffiliate.DataTextField = "PartnerAffiliatCodeName";
 ddlAffiliate.DataValueField = "AffiliateId";
 ddlAffiliate.DataBind();
 ddlAffiliate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
```